# vscode not warning unresolved function or methods

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, ide

[image: differences]

In webstorm this is easily spotted. I have disabled javascript validation because if I enable a lot of typescript type errors appears.

Is this possible to fix?

Answer (score 1):

VS Code will not report errors like that in JS files by default. To see unresolved property errors and similar, try enabling [type checking for JavaScript](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/working-with-javascript#_type-checking-javascript)

The quickest way to try this is to just add `// @ts-check` at the top of your js file

Comment: Thanks for your reply Matt.